# How to restrict route access in ktor framework?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

How to restrict **route** access in **ktor** framework?

```
//only admin           
post("/add") {
   call.respondText { "add" }
}

post("/delete") {
   call.respondText { "delete" }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe your problem in more detail? What type of middleware do you want to implement? Also, the API you mentioned isn't published yet.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware 
I want to restrict routs access by plugin.

Comment: In Ktor you can intercept pipelines to achieve a similar effect. For information about routes' interception please read the documentation https://ktor.io/docs/intercepting-routes.html#intercepting-any-route-node.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman 

Please please give me an example.
For example, we have three post methods and we want to limit them.

//only admins
post("add") {}
post("delete") {}

//only customer
post("show") {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a method that creates a route that restricts access for admins only. Inside that method, the newly created route is intercepted to inject the code for validation. In the following example, if the header `admin` has the value `1` then a request is made from an admin otherwise for the `/add` and `/delete` routes the response with the `401 Unauthorized` status will be returned.

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.auth.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.util.pipeline.*

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 5555, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        routing {
            admin {
                post("/add") {
                    call.respondText { "add" }
                }

                post("/delete") {
                    call.respondText { "delete" }
                }
            }

            post("/show") {
                call.respondText { "show" }
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = false)
}

private val validationPhase = PipelinePhase("Validate")

fun Route.admin(build: Route.() -> Unit): Route {
    val route = createChild(AdminSelector())

    route.insertPhaseAfter(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features, Authentication.ChallengePhase)
    route.insertPhaseAfter(Authentication.ChallengePhase, validationPhase)
    route.intercept(validationPhase) {
        if (!isAdmin(call.request)) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            finish()
        }
    }
    route.build()
    return route
}

class AdminSelector: RouteSelector() {
    override fun evaluate(context: RoutingResolveContext, segmentIndex: Int) = RouteSelectorEvaluation.Transparent
}

fun isAdmin(request: ApplicationRequest): Boolean {
    return request.headers["admin"] == "1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Have you reviewed version 2 of Ktor? Creating custom plugins has become easier. Is it possible to implement this code with the plugin?
https://ktor.io/docs/eap/custom-plugins.html

Comment: Yes, but it will require writing a hook. Also, your problem could be solved with the Authentication plugin https://ktor.io/docs/auth.html.

Comment: not working properly when using the custom plugins, 2.0.0-beta-1. even non admin is still checked

Comment: @ronscript this example is for Ktor 1.6.7.

Comment: Authentication.ChallengePhase Unresolved reference: ChallengePhase in version 2 on ktor help me please

Comment: Hi @AlekseiTirman
in Ktor 3-beta01 insertPhaseAfter and intercept is deprecated.
and show this warning :
Please use route scoped plugins instead.
can you please update your code with ktor 3-beta01?
Thank you

Comment: Please use my other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77921189/13963150).

Answer (score 2):

For Ktor 2.x the solution proposed by Alexsei does not work anymore because ChallengePhase is now marked as *internal* as they completely restructured the plugin system.

This code snippet seems to be working for me.

```
fun Route.authorization(build: Route.() -> Unit): Route {
    val route = createChild(CustomSelector())
    val plugin = createRouteScopedPlugin("CustomAuthorization") {
        on(AuthenticationChecked) { call ->
            val principal = call.authentication.principal
            // custom logic
        }
    }
    route.install(plugin)
    route.build()
    return route
}

private class CustomSelector : RouteSelector() {
    override fun evaluate(context: RoutingResolveContext, segmentIndex: Int) = RouteSelectorEvaluation.Transparent
}
```

Of course, you can add parameters to the function specifying the restriction like required roles.

To secure a route...

```
fun Route.myRoute() = route("test") {
    authorization {
        get { ... }
    }
}
```

For more details: https://ktor.io/docs/custom-plugins.html

Comment: Can now also be found in the official docs and as an example here: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/tree/main/codeSnippets/snippets/custom-plugin-authorization

Answer (score 0):

As another, more robust solution, you can use the [Authentication](https://ktor.io/docs/authentication.html) plugin and create a provider to check if the user is an admin. The following code works with Ktor `2.*` and `3.0.0-beta`:

```
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.auth.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        install(Authentication) {
            provider("admin") {
                authenticate { context ->
                    if (!isAdmin(context.call.request)) {
                        context.challenge("MyAuth", AuthenticationFailedCause.Error("Not an admin")) { challenge, call ->
                            call.respond(UnauthorizedResponse())
                            challenge.complete()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        routing {
            authenticate("admin") {
                get("/admin") {
                    call.respondText { "OK" }
                }
            }

            get("/everyone") {
                call.respondText { "OK" }
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}

fun isAdmin(request: ApplicationRequest): Boolean {
    return request.headers["admin"] == "1"
}
```